# Help me understand "The actions one takes are answered by consequences waiting at the conclusion"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I just watched the dubbed version of Code Geass anime series, and there's a sentence puzzling me.

> The actions one takes are answered by consequences waiting at the conclusion.

I was wondering whether the usage of the sentence is formal or not.

1. Can *action* use *answer* as a verb? I found nothing on the internet about *"the actions are answered by..."*
2. What does *"consequences waiting at the conclusion"* mean? Can *wait* use *at* as a prep?

<sub>I'm a non-native speaker of English.</sub>

Comment: Hello, Eric. Did my edits improve your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you for improving ,the format is better than the previous one

Comment: Because of how it's written, it sounds like a profound statement, but really it's just a basic statement that's more common sense than anything: *There are consequences to your actions*.

Comment: Hi Othya, so can I use this in composition? would it be strange?

Comment: The sentence under consideration is obviously a crude translation from some original Japanese "saying". Native Anglophones simply wouldn't be likely to think in terms of "actions" being "answered" by "conclusions", so it doesn't reflect natural use of English anyway. I think we should just note that the nearest equivalent in English is ***Actions have consequences*** and move on.

Comment: Since "are answered" is passive, it is not "actions" doing the answering, but being answered by something else (unstated what this is, but most likely God, the universe, the law of karma) ... so the "actions" are being acted upon by something else.

Comment: "consequences waiting at the conclusion" = not immediate consequences. Perhaps the intention is like at the end of life, judgement day, reincarnation, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *Can* action *use* answer *as a verb*?

Of course. In your post, it's a metaphorical usage that takes into account that every action has consequences, not all of which are predictable. Thus every action has the associated question, "What will happen?" Consider George W Bush proposing

> I know. Let's invade Iraq. What could go wrong?

Here's a non-hypothetical usage that uses the trope in a different sense, i.e., that actions are the result of demands from circumstances. From [*Caring: An Essay in the Philosophy of Ethics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xfjWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22actions%20which%20answer%22&dq=%22actions%20which%20answer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX1uf63drOAhXJOyYKHaiaD00Q6AEISzAI) by Stan Van Hooft:

> The matrix of affections and responsibilities which the cultural
>   formation of all persons establishes on the ground of their caring
>   comes to expression in **those actions which answer** the call of
>   those affections and responsibilities.

2. *Can* wait *use* at as a prep[osition]?

I submit the following from an undeniably credible source, The Monkees. From ["Last Train to Clarksville"](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Teawbt2vqqgj46ebasiqd7qtzzq?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics&u=0#):

> Take the last train to Clarksville.
>   I'll be **waiting at the station**.
>   We'll have time for coffee flavored kisses
>   And a bit of conversation.